# react native: How do I create a side menu with navigation between views using DrawerLayoutAndroid

Tags: android, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-router, drawerlayout

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to create a side menu with navigation using DrawerLayoutAndroid. I've looked this up but haven't really found anything helpful. Here's what I have for now:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  View,
  Image
} = React;
var ContentView = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.contentStyle}>Hello</Text>
      </View>
      );
  }
});
var Test = React.createClass({
  openD() {
    this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
  },
  render() {
    var navigationView = (
      <View style={styles.contentStyle}>
        <Text>First View</Text>
        <Text>Second View</Text>
        <Text>Third View</Text>
      </View>
    );

    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        drawerWidth={300}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        ref={'DRAWER'}
        renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.openD} underlayColor='transparent'>
            <Image 
            source={{uri:'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png'}} 
            style={styles.img}/>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <ContentView/>
        </View>
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }
});
```

And what it looks like: 
[Main View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EIQM.png)

[Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRMLi.png)

I'm asking for a simple example of adding navigation to this code so it could switch between views. Thanks in advance and sorry for such noob questions.

Comment: You can just go here for a complete example of what you want ... [Drawer with hamburger icon on Toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183688/how-to-use-drawerlayoutandroid-component-for-building-drawer-in-react-native-app/38189572#38189572)

Comment: If any problem do ask me...:D

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change your code a bit to render Navigator component itself and put what you already have in its renderScene method. It should be something like this:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  View,
  Image
} = React;
var ContentView = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.contentStyle}>Hello</Text>
      </View>
      );
  }
});
var Test = React.createClass({
  openD() {
    this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
  },
  renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
    var navigationView = (
      //Here you can pass the navigator objects to your views to push/pop them and navigate
      <View style={styles.contentStyle}>
        <Text>First View</Text>
        <Text>Second View</Text>
        <Text>Third View</Text>
      </View>
    );

    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        drawerWidth={300}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        ref={'DRAWER'}
        renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.openD} underlayColor='transparent'>
            <Image 
            source={{uri:'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png'}} 
            style={styles.img}/>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <ContentView/>
        </View>
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <Navigator
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
    />
  )}
});
```

Comment: really sorry to bother you again, but I kind of need some more help. Firstly, this code doesn't let me reach the openD() function, saying "undefined is not a function", which often happens when I try to call something using "this" outside of the render() function. And secondly, I have some real problems with Navigator, which is why I opened this question. I need a simple, but working example of reaching different views using Drawer. I would be really grateful if you could help me out. :)

Comment: 1. I updated my answer to use an arrow function to be able to use this and your function.


2. Read those well made tutorials:
https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.21e5i4nyz
http://blog.paracode.com/2016/01/05/routing-and-navigation-in-react-native/

And in addition with the code I gave you, you should have all you need.

Comment: I understand this seems easy to you, but the reason for opening this question was it's not easy for me. I understand WHAT to do, but I don't understand HOW to do it, that's why I've been asking for a simple example. I already know everything you've said so far. I simply don't know how to use it in my case.