# How to use DrawerLayoutAndroid component for building drawer in react-native apps?

Tags: android, menu, react-native, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I am new to react native and I am trying to build hamburger drawer to assist in navigation. But I could not find proper documentation. I found one but it was with redux so I let it go. Can anybody guide me how to create drawerlayout for react-native apps?

Comment: You can use AndroidToolbar for hamburger icon as in native android with DrawerLayoutAndroid ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take help from below code sample :
Your toolbar.js can be as:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
StyleSheet,
View,
Text
} from 'react-native';

var ToolbarAndroid = require('ToolbarAndroid');

class MyToolbar extends Component {
render() {
  var navigator = this.props.navigator;
   return (
    <ToolbarAndroid
     title={this.props.title}
     navIcon={require('./icons/ic_menu_white_24dp.png')}
     style = {styles.toolbar}
     titleColor={'white'} 
     onIconClicked={this.props.sidebarRef}/>
    );
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//define your own style
}  
 });

module.exports = MyToolbar;
```

And in for implementing drawer:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity, 
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

var ToolbarAndroid = require('ToolbarAndroid');
var MyToolbar = require('./MyToolbar');
var MenuItem = require('./MenuItem');

class OpenDraweFromToolbar extends Component {
 render() {

  var navigationView = (
     <ScrollView>
  <View style = {{height:100, backgroundColor:'blue', justifyContent:'center'}}>
     <Text style = {{height:25, color:'white', fontSize:25, marginLeft:20}}>Welcome To ReactNative</Text>
  </View>
  <ListView
       //render your list items
  </ScrollView>
);

return (
  <DrawerLayoutAndroid
    drawerWidth={300}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
    renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
    ref={'DRAWER'}>     
    <MyToolbar style={styles.toolbar}
        title={'Calendar'}
        navigator={this.props.navigator}
        {sidebarRef={()=>this._setDrawer()}}/>                  
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>            
      <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>Hello</Text>

    </View>
  </DrawerLayoutAndroid>  
);
}

 _setDrawer() {
   this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
  }  
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   //your own style implementation

 });

  module.exports = OpenDraweFromToolbar;
```

You should pass drawerlayout opening method as props to toolbar and in your toolbar component you should call sidebarRef as props, which automatically call the drawerlayout opening method of previous OpenDraweFromToolbar.js.

I hope you will get help from the above sample.Happy coding !!!

Comment: hey what does MenuItem file consist of? can you tell me the structure of MenuItem?

Comment: @atif MenuItem is the list of items to be rendered on the listview that is written as a separate component in the app.But now I have updated my code , you can see above..I have just rendered listview inside scrollview

Comment: how can i include toolbar in any activity? how can i call it from other class.

Comment: You can see that in the above code.Make toolbar a separate component as MyToolbar.js and include it whenever you want.Take reference from above sample.

Comment: i followed your instruction code worked well but still can see the toolbar in my screen here is the code ' var Toolbar = require(./toolbar)  ' by this i am accessing toolbar file and in render() i have accesed using <Toolbar />

Comment: if you could not see your toolbar then once check your toolbar style,set some background color....if problem still exists show me your toolbar code. You said it worked for you.. if it worked for you then you can accept this as the answer  :D

Comment: hey i got it working but i cant see the hamburger icon? why it is not getting rendered

Comment: 'navIcon={require('./icons/ic_menu_white_24dp.png')}' line will show the icon on toolbar..check your icon first in the folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116535/discussion-between-atif-and-riten).

Comment: Hi, i did not understand how to pass drawerlayout opening method as props to toolbar, hence clicking on menu icon drawer is not opening for me even after using the above code, can you please help?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not find toolbar.js in own Project. What is the path of the toolbar.js?

Comment: Sadly this example is missing the most important part - actually opening the drawer.